# LaTeX letter: undefined control sequence on \opening command

Tags: letters

I'm trying to use the \opening{} command in a LaTeX letter but getting an *undefined control sequence* error on it for some obscure reason.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}
\begin{document}

Dear John,

%Letter goes here

\end{document}
```

And minimal **not**-working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}
\begin{document}

\opening{Dear John,}

%Letter goes here

\end{document}
```

Note that for some reason the \closing{} command (not included above) works just fine. I'm using TexMaker and compiling with PdfLaTeX (but LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf doesn't work any better).

Any clue what's going on?

Comment: You have to enclose the letter text in the environment `letter` that takes as argument the addressee.

Comment: Well that was quick an on point, thank you!

Comment: I got the same error compiling a rather complex template with `scrlttr2` on a freshly installed machine. It turned out, that I had undefined commands in the document structure (I commented out a package I thought which was unused, but it was actually in use). Long story short, please be aware that this error message can be misleading and **not really related** to the `\opening`, but rather to **contents** of the cascade that is triggered by the `\opening` command.

Answer (score 4):

Many thanks to [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) for the quick answer, which is that the letter needs to be enclosed in a \begin{letter} … \end{letter} block, that I stupidly missed. Here's the working code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{}
\opening{Dear Johnny,}

%Letter goes here

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had `\begin{letter}{TO_ADDRESS}`, which was some Kile editor injected string that was causing my letter to fail to render, so I removed it and it worked. I appreciate the question.